# How to use `recover-session` and `dired-omit-mode` in Emacs 26 and lower?

Tags: dired, minor-mode, session, recover

Using Emacs 26.1, I have enabled `dired-omit-mode` globally with `(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook #'dired-omit-mode)`. When using `recover-session`, I don't see any files. How to fix this?

Creating a `.dir-locals.el` containing `((dired-mode (dired-omit-mode)))` didn't work.

---

This bug should be fixed in Emacs 27.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `dired-omit-mode`, add a wrapper to `dired-mode-hook` that checks `dired-directory`:

```lisp
(defun my-turn-on-dired-omit-mode ()
  (unless (and auto-save-list-file-prefix
               (string= dired-directory
                        (concat auto-save-list-file-prefix "*")))
    (dired-omit-mode)))
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook #'my-turn-on-dired-omit-mode)
;; (remove-hook 'dired-mode-hook #'dired-omit-mode)
```

Comment: This rather sounds like a bug which you should report with `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: done (15 chars)

Comment: More helpful than "(15 chars)" would be: https://debbugs.gnu.org/36223

Comment: I didn't know the link before I received the confirmation mail.